How to return a TypedResults.UnprocessableEntity in an ASP.NET Core Minimal API?
I'm trying to return an fffff from a Minimal API. When I set up the return type, I get a weird error:

the non-generic type 'IResults' cannot be used with type arguments.


public static async Task<Results<UnprocessableEntity<string>> HandleAsync(
    <snip>,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    return TypedResults.UnprocessableEntity("Unable to make any payments using Ezidebit because there's no EziDebit Digital Id registered.");
}

I can return other types here like <Task<Results<Ok, OK<string>, BadResult<string>>> etc.. Just this one TypedResult isn't working :(
Any suggestions, please?
Note: please ignore the screenshot that says I'm not returning it. Even when I change the code to return ssss; I still get the error.

Click the working Results while holding down CTRL, see what the full name of that Results class is. I believe you are missing a using directive in this file, or only a Results<T1, T2> type exists.

@shingo Results "family" of classes starts from 2 generic parameters. Which arguably makes sense =)

UnprocessableEntity<TValue> returned by TypedResults.UnprocessableEntity<TValue> is an IResult (and others interfaces treated by the framework):
public sealed class UnprocessableEntit1<TValue> : 
    IResult, 
    IStatusCodeHttpResult, 
    IValueHttpResult, 
    IValueHttpResult<TValue>, 
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Metadata.IEndpointMetadataProvider

So no need to wrap it in Results:
public static async Task<UnprocessableEntity<string>> HandleAsync(...)

or
public static async Task<IResult> HandleAsync(...)

And the Results family of classes starts from 2 generic parameters (your current code tries to use the non-generic static class Results which is similar to the TypedResults you use), hence it should be used when you have multiple types of results. For example:
Task<Results<UnprocessableEntity<string>, Ok<string>>> 


What happens if my method is returning multiple IResults ?

@Pure.Krome this is already covered in the answer - you use Results with 2+ generic parameters or just IResult. It's up to you what you prefer.

@Pure.Krome please check out also this and this answers.
